# How to move a drawable across the screen

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have been looking around for an answer to this and have not been finding much. I hope this is not hard to answer. What I want to do is have a drawable or an image move left to right or vise versa across my main menu screen. For example, if I had a picture of a cloud is there a way to have it start off the screen and move from left to right across it and the loop back to the beginning. The picture of the cloud would stay the same and it would just move across the screen. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Translation framework to achieve this, this works as:

```
TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
```

So you need to write your code for moving view in x-axis direction, as follows:

```
 mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 599, 0, 0);
    mAnimation.setDuration(10000);
    mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    view.setAnimation(mAnimation);
```

Comment: Now would these go in my main activity or in an xml? Also, where would I declare my drawable image to use?

Comment: set image drawable as resource to imageView, which I has taken view.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Does the mAnimation go in one of my activities?