# How to animate Text view like marquee?

Tags: android, animation

I have a  text view  i need to marquee those along the screen(like the flash news flashing on news channels) using animation.now how can i implement this in android i tried  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344349/android-marquee)

but did not get the solution please help?

Comment: have you tried animation framework.

Comment: no how do i use that please explain?

Comment: check link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138375/how-to-move-a-drawable-across-the-screen/9138560#9138560

Comment: Refer to this link

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344349/android-marquee][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344349/android-marquee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

main.xml

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/mywidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textColor="#ff4500"
    android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text" 
     />
```

java Class

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.mywidget);  
    tv.setSelected(true);  // Set focus to the textview
```

Comment: do i need to do anything in my java file for this effect

Comment: Android(User): yes am going to edit your answer we need little bit modification to do this